# ios - How to load javascript function into UIWebview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, access-token

I'm building an app using OpenID, now I want to get access token, please go through this given link

http://www.stevesaxon.me/posts/2011//window-external-notify-in-ios-uiwebview

In that link javascript function is given

```
<script type=\"text/javascript\">

    window.external =

    {
        'Notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; },
        'notify': function(s) { document.location = 'acs://settoken?token=' + s; }
    };

</script>
```

How to load this javascript in `UIWebview`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The class UIWebView has a method called **stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString** which you can use to load javascript code to a webview.

I use this method to execute javasctipt on my webview:

```
-(void) runjs:(NSString *)code
{
    @try 
    {
        if (webview)
            [webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: code];      
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the UIWebView method called:

stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script;

```
NSString *result = [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(@"alert('Hi')")];
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply Avi

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to call the javascript from html to iOS webview

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"my_html_function();"];
```

this may help you.